# Copy all objects to another S3 bucket in different region with different structure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket in Region A structured like this:

```
ProviderA-1-1
    31423423.jpg
ProviderB-1-1
    32423432.jpg
```

The top level folder is a unique image identifier. The filename is the *version* of the image.

i want to copy the images to a bucket in Region B, structured like this:

```
ProviderA-1-1.jpg
ProviderB-1-1.jpg
```

E.g i don't care about the version. I just want the folder name (which is unique) to be the filename.

The reason i'm doing this is to have a flat structure to make use of image services like Imgix / ImageKit. (they provide on the fly image transformation for images, given a flat source origin)

So, my requirements are:

1. I need to copy lots (millions of images, ~10TB) of images
2. The destination bucket is in another region
3. I need to 'flatten' the structure, and change the name of the images to be the name of the folder they are in (folder names isn't fixed)

I've seen a few answers here suggesting the aws cli is the best approach, but not sure how i can achieve 3. with that?

Sounds like i need to loop through the images one by one, changing the name before i copy. If a script is suggested, i'm most comfortable with .NET - so perhaps the AWS .NET SDK?

This is a once off job, where i need to move the images as quickly and cheaply as possible.

Advice please?

Thanks :)

Comment: Given "folder names isn't fixed" I would say you'll at least have to write a script. It's hard to say which way (multipart copy, parallel `aws cli cp` or something else) would perform fastest without some testing. I'll come back tomorrow and see if I can at least show some example with `aws s3 ls`, `dirname` and `xargs -P` or GNU `parallel`.

Comment: @Kashyap that would be awesome and much appreciated, thank you! I don't have much experience with AWS, so i'd be going in blind..

Comment: How are you going to handle name clashes, eg `foo/bar.jpg` and `blah/bar.jpg`? _WHY_ do you need to flatten the structure and move it to another region? If you can provide more information, we might be able to provide a better answer.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein i edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a script is required because you are moving and renaming the files.

If you're comfortable with .NET, then use that!

The basic program would be:

- Create two [S3 clients](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/TS3Client.html) -- one for source bucket (to obtain the listing) and one for the destination bucket (because copy commands are sent to the destination bucket, which pulls the file from the source bucket) because you are using a different region
- Use [`ListObjects()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/MS3ListObjectsString.html) to obtain a list of the source bucket. Note that it will return 1000 files at a time, so use `NextMarker` to request the subsequent batch.
- Loop through each file and use [`CopyObject()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/MS3CopyObjectStringStringStringString.html) to simultaneously copy and rename the file. Use your own logic to take the folder name and convert it to a filename. Each file will be copied directly between the buckets, without needing to download/upload
- Continue, looping through the list of 1000 files and then get the next 1000 files, etc.

The process could be sped up by using multi-threading but the logic gets a bit hard. It might be easier to simply run a few copies of the program at the same time, each handling a different Prefix range (effectively, folder names).

It's a one-off job, so optimization isn't important.

If you are adding more files in future, the best method would be to create an **AWS Lambda function that is triggered whenever a new file is created in S3**. The Lambda function would then copy the file to the destination, then exit.

Comment: Thanks for this, great answer (+1). Can you please clarify the 'two s3 clients' point? It looks like `CopyObject()` needs to work off a single `AmazonS3Client`? So not sure how i can copy across region? (the client would be on the destination region right? but the 'source' bucket is in a _different_ region/client?)

Comment: Correct. The `CopyObject()` command would be issued against the client associated with the destination region. It will retrieve the data from the specified source bucket. The command takes a destination bucket+key and a source bucket+key.

Comment: so how will it work then? The source is a _different_ client? The source/dest needs to be the same client / region?

Comment: When you issue the `CopyObject()` command, it is done on a client that is initialized earlier in the code. A region is specified when the client is created. Any commands sent to that client will be sent to the region specified. The `CopyObject()` command (which is issued on that client) specifies the S3 source bucket+key and the destination bucket+key (without mentioning regions). I suggest you just start writing the code and see how you go!

Comment: Yeah, i did.. works. :) I was confused by the fact the 'source bucket' in client doesn't have to be the same region. The fact you create a client with a region implies all operations are bound to that region, but it's not the case. Anyway, works. Thank you :)

Comment: One last question - regarding optimisation. _Where_ should i run this script? A machine near the 'source' region, or the 'destination' region? Also, I can't run a script per prefix range, since i don't actually _know_ the folder names beforehand... so i guess multi-threading the `CopyObjectAsync` call is the best approach?

Comment: You can run it on any computer connected to the Internet. Location doesn't matter because S3 will talk to S3, not via your computer. If speed is important you could multi-thread, but if it is a one-off activity, just run it overnight single-threaded. Or, chop the range in half and run two copies simultaneously. It all depends on how fast you need it to be.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173734/discussion-between-rpm1984-and-john-rotenstein).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have no location constraints set up for your buckets, flattening would simply be:

```
aws s3 cp --recursive s3://source_bucket/foo/ s3://target_bucket/
```

assumes you have the [CLI installed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html) and required [credentials setup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html) correctly. Or you can pass them on command line:

```
aws --profile profile_A2B --region XXX s3 cp --recursive s3://source_bucket/foo/ s3://target_bucket/ --acl yyy
```

You don't mention any performance requirements. There are many ways of making transfer faster, depends on many factors. Few blind hints I can give are:

- See if [transfer acceleration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html) can help you.
- In general S3 to S3 transfer is faster than S3 to/from non-S3 location.
- See if you can create parallel batches by prefix like:

.

```
for prefix in {a..z}
do
    aws s3 cp --recursive s3://source_bucket/foo/${prefix}* s3://target_bucket/ &
done
```

If this is not a one time transfer and the transfer acceleration isn't cutting it for you, consider:

- download from S3 (in region A) to a local HDD residing in region A.
- transfer from local HDD in region A to a local HDD in region B using other methods like [Aspera](https://asperasoft.com/) or [FileCatalyst](http://filecatalyst.com/products/faq.html) or whatever else you can find.
- upload from local HDD in region B to S3 (in region B).

I have no practical data to share except that Aspera blows things like FTP out of water, it's not even a competition. YMMV.

---

John already covered the pseudo code. I'll just make one change to it. Write two separate programs, one to fetch the list of filenames and second to copy. It takes a *lot of time* to list files if you have millions of them.

Once you've listed the file names in a file, say one per line, it would be pretty easy to parallelize given you can split the file (say `split -l 1000 file_list splits`).

Use `xargs -P` or gun `parallel` to run multiple `aws s3 cp` commands at once. If you're using shell instead of .NET.

Finally don't forget to set the ACL (and other attributes like TTL etc) on target files during the copy. Doing that after the copy will take a long time.

Comment: hi, thanks for this. i'll edit my question with a few clarifications

Comment: can't use transfer acceleration. :( "_the bucket name must conform to DNS naming requirements and must not contain periods (".")._" (bucket has a `.`)